# Displaying Data from Database PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo

I want to present the data from my database in a fairly readable and organized fashion. At the moment, my data looks like this:

```
Array
(
[ID] => 25
[0] => 25
[storename] => ABCDE
[1] => ABCDE
[receipt] => 22222
[2] => 22222
[date_visit] => 02/07/2015
[3] => 02/07/2015
[associates] => Test associate
[4] => Test associate
[greeted] => yes
[5] => yes
[greeted_explanation] => test greeted
[6] => test greeted
```

Which is pretty hard to read. It's important that each users input is separate (i.e. not listed as a table) but I don't need it to say 'Array' or even list the column number '[0] => 25' (with the arrow) for example. How do I get rid of these elements? I can play around with the font etc after, but I don't know how to get rid of the other stuff. I guess it's probably how i'm fetching the data:

```
 $pdo = new PDO( "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host" , $user , $password );

 if ( $pdo ) 
 {
echo "<pre>";
foreach( $pdo->query( "select * from survey" ) as $k )
 {
print_r( $k );
 }

 }
```

Maybe there's a way for me to pull each column in the database separately (i.e. ask it to bring in 'ID', then to bring in 'storename' etc? I tried doing some research but every record takes me to the formatted example above and I can't believe anyone wants to display their data like that.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you can use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Thank you. Which part of my code do I change? V.new to PDO.

Comment: You seem new to PHP too. :)

Comment: Yes. I learnt very basic MySQL and was told it needed to be PDO, so now i'm almost starting over. I'm almost there but it's taken me days and days of research and I am having trouble finding any good tutorials online. Thought it would be simple and some guru would be able to answer it for me, but instead someone marks my question as lacking in research - i've spent the last 5 days researching :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdo = new PDO( "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host" , $user , $password );

 if ( $pdo ) 
 {
   echo "<pre>";

   foreach( $pdo->query( "select * from survey",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k )
   {
       print_r( $k );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why someone marked this as unhelpeful but it worked for me. I still have the word 'Array' and the arrows => in there. Is there anyway to get rid of them?